# Hard disk Free fall sensor driver

Tags: hard-drive, drivers

Why do I need the driver for my free fall sensor hard drive?

I thought it is a technology inside the disk that work seamlessly.

If I don't install proper driver my free fall sensor would not work?

Comment: You shouldn't need any driver. What's the hard disk model?

Comment: laptop dell studio 1558, hdd seagate st9320423as

Comment: Where did you find the information that a driver is needed?

Comment: I nave a st Micro sensor in device manager

Comment: The functionality of the sensor **should be** fully automatic.  The drive just lets windows know what is happening.

Comment: @cybernard this is what i thought, i was just wondering.